# Prompt ideas on how to generate a character performing a kick in Midjourney?

Tags: prompt-design, midjourney

I've been trying for hours to generate a kicking action in MJ, but can't find the right prompt, tried "karate, tae kwon do, flying kick, kicking, performing kick", but nothing seems to have the proper effect. Punching is pretty easy but kicking is giving me a headache.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

I am experimenting with the same thing. This is where I am so far.

> /imagine prompt Amidst the serene backdrop of a traditional martial arts dojo, a highly skilled black male martial artist is in mid-air, executing a flawless and breathtaking martial arts kick. His body is a symphony of precision and power as his leg extends gracefully, demonstrating the culmination of years of training and discipline. The swift motion of his kick is captured frozen in time, showcasing not only his physical prowess but also the elegance of martial arts in action.

Check the type of kick, or change mid-air with "one foot on ground". From this you can upscale one that suits you and use it for a reference (a web address where the image is kept) and a seed value (produced by adding a reaction to the image and then DMing... that will produce a seed number you can then use in the prompt, e.g. --seed 873428438768)

So altogether it might look like this...

> /imagine prompt https://s.mj.run/y7IgSsdfHE Amidst the serene backdrop of a traditional martial arts dojo, a highly skilled black male martial artist is on one foot, executing a flawless and karate high kick. His body is a symphony of precision and power as his leg extends gracefully, demonstrating the culmination of years of training and discipline. The swift motion of his kick is captured frozen in time, showcasing not only his physical prowess but also the elegance of martial arts in action. --seed 4234234234

Happy upscaling... hope this helps.

You could also try referencing images of kicks from the web.

This is a working sample that did me well:

> /imagine prompt https://s.mj.run/xgUgyU1ZYPM https://s.mj.run/inpHOrhmpg8 https://s.mj.run/SrC3aE9g50I Amidst the serene backdrop of a traditional martial arts dojo, a highly skilled black male martial artist is on one foot, executing a flawless karate side kick. His body is a symphony of precision and power as his leg extends gracefully, demonstrating the culmination of years of training and discipline. The swift motion of his kick is captured frozen in time, showcasing not only his physical prowess but also the elegance of martial arts in action.